# Why is ImageSource called twice in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

My app changes pictures with a button click. However, when I watch it with a breakpoint, the ImageSource's property is referenced twice each time. The other properties are only referenced once.

**Why is the ImageSource "get" running twice?**

Specifically, this line runs two times, back to back, right after `PropertyChanged()`:
 `get { return picture; }`

This is how I update the image in the GUI:

```
public class ApplicationState : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ImageSource picture;

    public ImageSource Picture
    {
        get { return picture; }
        set
        {
            picture = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Picture");
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the XAML code for the image:
`<Image Source="{Binding Path=Picture}"/>`

And the picture change is triggered with:
`Picture = Convert(picturePath);`

Am I missing something? Why would it ever run twice back to back?

**Edit:**
Microsoft explains some of the reason in [this note](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/770169/unexpected-behaviour-binding-engine-getting-imagesource-twice).

Comment: What does the stack trace say about where the two calls are coming from?

Comment: @Tim - All I see is hidden external code in the stack trace.

Comment: The last part of the note you're referencing explains exactly why the getter is called twice: *the extra call arises because you have a property (but not a DependencyProperty) whose return type derives from DependencyObject. In this case, WPF may need to listen to "subproperty" changes from the value itself, and needs to fetch that value in order to decide whether the need is actually present. This is independent of the actual data-transfer, so it uses its own call to the property-getter.*